# Examples of rings of regular function on explicit open sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

*The following is a problem I've been set:*

> (a) Find $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ where $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $U=X\setminus\mathbb{V}(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)$.
>
> (b) Find $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ where $X=\mathbb{V}(xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ and
>
> (i) $p=(0,0)$;
>
> (ii) $p=(0,1)$.

*Here is what I've got so far.*

(a) Let $f=x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2$.
We know that, for $Y=\mathbb{A}^3$,
$$\mathcal{O}_Y(U) = A(Y)_f = k[x_0,x_1,x_2]\big(\{1,f,f^2,\ldots\}\big)^{-1} = \left\{\frac{g}{f^n} : g\in k[x_0,x_1,x_2],n\geqslant0 \right\}.$$
**But how do we deal with the case given, since it isn't affine?**

(b) Since everything is affine, we know that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p} = A(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_p}$ where $\mathfrak{m}_p = \{f\in A(X) : f(p)=0\}$ is a maximal ideal of $A(X)$.
So $$\mathcal{O}_{X,p} = \left\{\frac{g}{f} : g\in k[x,y],\,\, f(p)\neq0\right\}$$
Hence when $p=(0,0)$, we require that $f$ has a non-zero constant term, **but I don't see what more we can say about when $p=(0,1)$?**
**(Also, is all the above actually right?)**

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ah yes, I should have spotted that, I'll have another go with that in mind. Any helpful hints about part (b)?

Comment: For (b)(ii):  $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=k[y]_{(y-1)}$. The point $(0,1)$ doesn't see the $x$-axis and doesn't care about it. So you may just as well study $V(x)=Spec(k[y])$ at $y=1$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Although I get the gist of what you're saying, I'm not yet good enough at algebraic geometry to fully understand how to formalise that...